# shell script to install aws cli, java,

Tags: bash, shell

I am running a shell script to enable cli sso(single sign on) between okta+aws/s3 as below,

```
#!/bin/bash


PREFIX=~/.okta bash <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aws-cli-assume-role/master/bin/install.sh) -i

cat >>.bash_profile <<EOF

#OktaAWSCLI
if [[ -f "$HOME/.okta/bash_functions" ]]; then
    . "$HOME/.okta/bash_functions"
fi
if [[ -d "$HOME/.okta/bin" && ":$PATH:" != *":$HOME/.okta/bin:"* ]]; then
    PATH="$HOME/.okta/bin:$PATH"
fi

EOF

cp ~/.okta/config.properties ~/.okta/config.properties_bck

cat >~/.okta/config.properties <<EOF
OKTA_ORG=dev-728773-admin.okta.com
OKTA_AWS_APP_URL=https://dev-728773.okta.com/home/amazon_aws/0oah1fb9k5nxiyKMk356/272
OKTA_ENV_MODE=true
EOF

source .bash_profile
```

but more likely my script need to verify java, okta aws cli, aws cli, script should configure the PATH & env variables in order to access code you pushed in ~/.okta/ directory.
Execute the command “okta-aws, I should get all the above output.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, there is a lot of code here.  Is there is one specific thing you are struggling with?

Comment: If add source ~/.bash_profile in my shell script it is not working okta-aws, When i run manully this is working anil@ip-172-31-30-150:~$ source ~/.bash_profile
anil@ip-172-31-30-150:~$ okta-aws
Username:......